# How can build a Python app when this is execute can start Web Server and Python programs on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

In short I'm working on a system control Raspberry GPIO from web app write Python. 
I was wondering if how can build an app when start it run all services such as web server, python programs, web app in raspberry pi?

Comment: You want to reinvent supervisord (and some others)?

Comment: Check out cherrypy, it's a web server written in python, so you can call python code from web transactions.